# Lightning Map: Allow user to drop a marker on map

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura

I am planning to create a component (aura/lwc) that allows users to select a location by dropping a marker on the map. I tried to go through the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation), but couldn't find anything related to this. Also are there any other options that provide this functionality.
Example:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the standard out of box component. The current version renders the Map component using an iframe and does not expose the `Map` object or any events to handle mouse or click events.

You will need to roll your own Maps component if you need to achieve. A good place to start will be exploring the Maps JavaScript API. Look into how you can tie the Mouse click event documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-click-latlng#maps_event_click_latlng-javascript)

Note that Salesforce locker will also come into play and it will be a lot easy to build with Visualforce and iframe inside LWC and use LMS to handle any messages to Lightning Container.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in checking my post here : https://munawirrahman.medium.com/pinpoint-map-location-with-salesforce-flow-with-leaflet-js-3943dc44d0d0

I built a solution for flow users to move/drag the map marker. That component utilizing leaflet Js library and you can set the default location of the map when its loaded.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Munawir. Do you know if this solution will work in Lightning Locker or the latest Lightning Web Security?